# smtp error please have a glance

Tags: c#, sockets, smtp

i am facing this exception while making email delivery system, could any body explain this ...

> {System.Net.Mail.SmtpException:
>   Failure sending mail. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: Unable to
>   connect to the remote server --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No
>   connection could be made because the
>   target machine actively refused it
>   at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint
>   endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress
>   socketAddress)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalConnect(EndPoint
>   remoteEP)    at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean
>   connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6,
>   Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception&
>   exception)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream
>   PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean
>   async, IPAddress& address, Socket&
>   abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6,
>   Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object
>   owningObject, Boolean async, Int32
>   timeout, GeneralAsyncDelegate
>   asyncCallback)    at
>   System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object
>   owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate
>   asyncCallback)    at
>   System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object
>   owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate
>   asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout) 
>   at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(String
>   host, Int32 port)    at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(String
>   host, Int32 port)    at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
>   at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage
>   message)    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage
>   message)    at
>   Email.mailWrapper.Send(String strTo,
>   String strFrom, String strSubject,
>   String strBody) in C:\Documents and
>   Settings\asd\My Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2005\Projects\PlacementManager\Email\mailWrapper.cs:line
>   158}

Comment: Did you see the "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" line?

Comment: Post the line of code where you open the socket to the server.  Otherwise it's impossible to know what you're doing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it)

Answer (score 1):

It's just saying that whatever port you've configured your `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` to is being blocked on the server by a firewall, or else it's not even listening on that port.

Comment: but my fire wall is off....i am making it for local machine
please let me know if u caught the problem

Comment: In that case, the port is not even listening.  It would help to know what port you configured your SmtpClient to use, and what port you have an SMTP server running on on your localhost.

Comment: SMTP server running on port 25, but  how to know what port SmtpClient uisng