# Cannot connect to a database using Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to connect to a db using Symfony2. However it returns:

> Internal server error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. "
>
> Details about the error
>
> [1/2] ErrorException: Warning: PDO::__construct(): [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
> (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:7555) in C:\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\doctrine-dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php line 36

Can anyone help me solve this error ?

Comment: "because the target machine actively refused it".

Comment: That port looks odd. Are you sure your DB server listens on it? Can you connect with some other tool?

Comment: Possible duplicate conetent : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it. Else maybe go to see this article : http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/58761/No-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-ma

Answer (score 1):

This happen when the SQL Server is not started yet.
Start your MySQL Server in your XAMPP, WAMP, LAMP or any server that you use.