# How to Send Mail in Asp.net in C#

Tags: asp.net, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it)

I Face Critical Problem During Sending Mail in Asp.net please tell me Solution if Anyone know About this. 
This Is My Code for Sending Mail

```
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

        mm.From = new MailAddress(txtfrom.Text);

        mm.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtto.Text));



        mm.Subject = txtsubject.Text;

        mm.Body = txtmessage.Text;

        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;

        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //You can add this in the webconfig

        smtp.EnableSsl = true;

        System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();

        NetworkCred.UserName = "mymail@gmail.com";

        NetworkCred.Password = "my password";
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;

        smtp.Port = 587; //this is Gmail port for e-mail

        smtp.Send(mm);//send an e-mail
```

The Problem is That when i Click on Send Button it Show following Error

> "No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it 173.194.79.109:587"

Please tell me Solution ..

Comment: Why are you setting UseDefaultCredentials to true? This will try to send the credentials of the currently logged on user, not the ones you have initialised - set this to false and retry.

Comment: ref [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail) and set `UseDefaultCredentials` to `false` as you are specifying your custom credentials

Answer (score 0):

you need to set **false** the `UseDefaultCredentials` property.

```
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

Comment: i Set  smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false; but it not Working

Answer (score 0):

That error message usually means a firewall is blocking your connection.  Instead of using your machine name `"173.194.79.109:587"`, try using "`localhost`".

Comment: Sir i Use All of Your Above Code but its not Working Even i Set 
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false; 
but it Also Show Error "Unable to Connect Remote Server"???

Please tell me Particular Solution......

Thanks For Good Response on my Question All of u..

Comment: Are you using any antivirus on your system?

Comment: Yes   i use Macfee Antivirus on my pc

Comment: Try to remove it and check as mainly that causes issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use it.

```
SmtpClient gglClient = new SmtpClient("173.194.67.108", 587);
gglClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
gglClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
gglClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "password");
gglClient.EnableSsl = true;

MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("", email);
msg.Subject = "";
msg.Body = @" ";

msg.IsBodyHtml = false;
msg.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;

gglClient.Timeout = 8000;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain,
        SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };

gglClient.Send(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void SendMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var fromAddress = new MailAddress(fromid.Text, fromname.Text);
        var toAddress = new MailAddress(toid.Text, toname.Text);
        string fromPassword = pswd.Text;
        string subject = subjectbox.Text;
         string body = bodybox.Text;

        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword),
            Timeout = 20000
        };
        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body,
            IsBodyHtml = false

        })
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the function which i checked to send mail...and it's working properly.

`

```
    private static bool testsendemail(MailMessage messageBody)
    {

        try

        {

        MailMessage message1 = new MailMessage();

        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

        string msg = string.Empty;

        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("FromMail@Test.com");
        message1.From = fromAddress;
        message1.To.Add("ToMail@Test1.com");
        message1.Subject = "This is Test mail";
        message1.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message1.Body ="You can write your body here"+messageBody;
        smtpClient.Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"; // We use yahoo as our smtp client
        smtpClient.Port = 587;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new  System.Net.NetworkCredential("SenderMail@yahoo.com", "YourPassword");

        smtpClient.Send(message1);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}`
```

Thank You.