# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:56789

Tags: sockets, connection

I am facing an issue with my socket connection. I have a web Service in Project and It connect to a service installed in the same server. The Service is getting crashed and it has successfully restarted by another monitoring application in our project. But when the web method tries to access the method in the service I am getting a web exception. But when we restart the service manually it works fine. Here is web exception I am getting and Code used.

**Code Using**

```
string url = "http://localhost:56789/" + SERVICE_NAME;
m_target = Activator.GetObject(typeof(IWebServiceInterface), url) as IWebServiceInterface;
if (IPAddress.TryParse(ipAddress, out ip))
 {
   status = m_target.Connect(Session.SessionID, username, stationId, ip);           
 }
```

**Web Exception**

> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   TerminalInterface.IWebServiceInterface.Connect(String sessionId,
>   String username, Int32 stationId, IPAddress ipAddress)    at
>   myWebProject.WebServices.Terminal.Service.Connect(String username,
>   Int32 stationId, String ipAddress)
>   18:42:28.953  ProLog: System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the
>   remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection
>   could be made because the target machine actively refused it
>   127.0.0.1:56789    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalConnect(EndPoint remoteEP)    at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout,
>   Exception& exception)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http.HttpClientTransportSink.ProcessAndSend(IMessage
>   msg, ITransportHeaders headers, Stream inputStream)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http.HttpClientTransportSink.ProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream,
>   ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SoapClientFormatterSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg)

Comment: try to run at CMD netstat -a, could you see someone listening at port 56789?

Comment: Hi Pollano thanks for the reply,The issue is we can not reproduce this it happen only in that environment(windows 2003 r2- 32 bit).

Comment: The issue is either that nothing was listening at port 56789 at the moment when you ran that code, or maybe the Windows firewall got in the way.

Comment: This [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14079317/1577396) might help you.