# Target Machine Actively Refused It

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to connect a client-server system on a laptop, build using visual studio 2008. and i got this error

> No Connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8;

I have tried the PC's IP address but not sure which port to use and how to check which port is used. I also ticked all private and public checkboxes in the firewall options to all them.

any clue why the error keeps on appearing?

Comment: This error appears because you cannot use that port to connect to it. If it's not listening on port "8", then it will refuse a connection there.

Comment: http://www.lextm.com/2012/10/already-in-use-then-who-uses-it.html

Comment: What's the server? Why do you not know which port it's listening on?

Comment: got it. i use netstat to figure it out. thanks guys!

Comment: I think it'd be better if you write your answer don there to make your post useful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it)