# TcpClient error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refuses it

Tags: c#, vb.net, exception, network-programming, tcpclient

I wrote a simple tcp/ip chat and it worked with the localhost IP(127.0.0.1) as well as connecting to another computer on the local network.
Through the Internet (v4 IP address) it didn't work so I tried the [codeproject example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38914/A-TCP-IP-Chat-Program):

I downloaded but it threw the same exception on connecting:

```
TcpClient Client = New TcpClient(IPAddr, 65535);
```

I tried with another port and turned off Windows-Firewall and Avira-Free.

**Update:**
If I connect to another Internet IP address, the following exception is thrown:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond IP-Address: 65535

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it).

Comment: Either the port is being blocked or there is nothing listening at the other end

Comment: @Brian I updated my question, and in that question the localhost ip-address is used, which is working on my computer. But I'll give it a try, thanks

Comment: The error message in your title has nothing to do with the error message in your question. Which is it you are asking about?

Comment: @EJP If I want to connect to my internet IP, the title-error is shown, if I connect to another internet IP, the 2. error (update) is shown.

Comment: @xoxox - Can you try this example and tell me if you still have problems? The download is at the top of the page. http://www.networkcomms.net/creating-a-wpf-chat-client-server-application/

Comment: Your target machine's IP might not be public IP. You can try by pinging the target machine's IP, you should be able to ping the target machine's IP.

Comment: @MarcF Thank you, I'll try it, but I doubt that this works, I rather think it's the problem mentioned by Ashish

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably this won't help, but perhaps try another port?