# Error connecting to SQL C#

Tags: c#, sql, database-connection

I need to connect to a sql server instance on a network, but I get the error

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I've set the port to 1433, checked that the TCP/IP is enabled, checked that sql can allow remote connections, the firewall is off so that's not the issue.

I just need to connect and read data from a sql database. any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: Code adds weight to your question. so share it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it

Comment: Can you connect using the same credentials, outside of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the server with the sql server instance, and enter the SQL Server Configuration Manager. Check the settings and especially that TCP IP is enabled. If not, enable it and restart the SQL Server service.

It is also possible that the Named Pipes setting being disabled may be causing this.

Sorry just reread your question, I didnt see the bit where you checked TCP! ignore the previous comment