# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it C#

Tags: c#

I tried to play around with malware stranger sent me. I open it in vmware and run microsoft network monitor
[screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/icgcgqtql/)

So I tried to make tcp connection using C# like this:

```
TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");    
tcpclnt.Connect("darcometweb.no-ip.org", 225);
tcpclnt.Close();
```

but it throws exception: Message    "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 95.244.217.192:225"

To make sure I also tried it in Python but it also throws the same exception

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
host = 'darcometweb.no-ip.org'
port = 225

s.connect((host,port))
s.close
print 'done'
```

Anyone knows what is wrong ?

@ Syed Ali Taqi: I have looked into that question, however in my case the malware can make connection but my c# app can't

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it)

Comment: Did you opened port 225 in your firewall? Sometimes, systems block low number porsts (like yours). Try something bigger (e.g. 77777).

Comment: @Fka: 77777 doesn't exist - max port number is 65535.

Comment: Yes, indeed :P I just mentioned to use higher number, but you are right of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually happens when the port is closed/ no port forwarding on the router/ firewall or anti virus blocking the connection.

First open command line and type

netstat -a

to see all the open connections and ports, if your port listed then go to
[Open port checker](http://canyouseeme.org/) and type in your port to see if there is an access from outside your network.
If no i would go with port forwarding then, windows firewall, anti virus.