# Visual studio 2010 not detecting the namespaces

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, namespaces

Visual studio 2010 not detecting the namespaces

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;
```

Hence i am not able to use the below line

```
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

It was working proper bt suddenly its not detecting. I googled itand found [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it).

But how to make it working ?

Should i turn firewall off.? What is the best solution for that?.

Comment: what do you mean by not detecting namespace? "Hence i am not able to use the below line" -: What code are you using now?

Comment: Are you getting any compile time error? If yes then please add in question definition.

Comment: Usually when we add namespaces automatically system will detect the name when we type the starting letters, but in my case its not happening.

Comment: Make sure you have Added System.Data dll reference to your project.