# "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Tags: c#, iis

Not sure if this is the right place to post this as it's not looking like a programming issue but was wondering if anyone else has had similar issues. Just to save time I've already looked at all the posts on stack overflow that are similar but none of them cured the issue.

Ive made an app for Windows CE 6.5 device. I am connecting to a web service in the code, when I run the code as a test everything returns fine. The web service is running and the code to retrieve the information is correct.

Now that I know this is working I debug the app in VS2008 on the Windows CE 6.5 device connected to the PC via USB. When I do this I get the following error.

> "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

I've tried a load of different suggestions to cure this but have not found any yet.

Web service is running on IIS and accessing a SQL database.

Has anyone any suggestions to what is causing this?

Comment: is there a firewall blocking the connection? are you using the correct protocol? are you using the correct credentials?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, firewall is turned off, antivirus is disabled. Correct protocol is being used and correct credentials are being used as the code works when tested.

Comment: show the connection string you are using to try to connect to the database. Can you also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it

Comment: Also I can ping the device so the network connection is fine. Getting internal network and internet

Comment: Connection string is fine, works for everything and when run as a test the code connects to the database fine. Calling the Web Service from the device via url and tested the url also which works fine on localhost and on another windows pc.

Comment: well, you're not providing much to go on. have you checked the link i provided? what is the configuration string you are using to connect to the database? You say "I've tried a load of different suggestions to cure this" but you haven't said what these are.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94815/discussion-between-ryan-mckinney-and-user1666620).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to the problem, seems to be SDK related. Create a new CE 5.0 app as a test and everything works as it should.