# Why is my Acceptor refusing connections?

Tags: c#, quickfix

I have used "Executor" from QuickFixN docs to create a test client-server app.

This is my Acceptor cgf:

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=acceptor
SocketAcceptPort=398
SocketAcceptHost=127.0.0.1
StartTime=00:00:01
EndTime=23:00:00
FileLogPath=c:\CurrentLogs\DummyServer
UseDataDictionary=Y
ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=Y
HeartBtInt=30

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.2
SenderCompID=DUMMYSERVER
TargetCompID=DUMMYCLIENT
FileStorePath=c:\CurrentLogs\DummyServerStore
DataDictionary=c:\FIX\FIX42.xml
```

This is the initiator cfg:

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
SocketConnectPort=398
SocketConnectHost=127.0.0.1
StartTime=00:00:01
EndTime=23:00:00
FileLogPath=c:\CurrentLogs\DummyClient
UseDataDictionary=Y
ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=Y
HeartBtInt=30

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.2
SenderCompID=DUMMYCLIENT
TargetCompID=DUMMYSERVER
FileStorePath=c:\CurrentLogs\DummyClientStore
DataDictionary=c:\FIX\FIX42.xml
```

I get Session Created message from Acceptor - but no sign of connection from Initiator.

From initator logs I get:

> 20161206-11:34:47.867 : Created session 20161206-11:34:47.886 :
>   Connecting to 127.0.0.1 on port 398 20161206-11:34:48.896 : Connection
>   failed: No connection could be made because the target machine
>   actively refused it 127.0.0.1:398

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try removing "SocketAcceptHost", you don't need that.  I have a gut feeling that it's causing something odd to happen on your machine.

Comment: Is your port open ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it