# I cannot establish a connection to MonetDB using pymonetDB in Python

Tags: python, sql, monetdb

I'm trying to use MonetDB in Python to perform some tasks on a huge dataframe. I've installed the suggested API and it has successfully loaded. But when I try to establish the connection, I always get the same error:

```
[Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

In my research, people have said that I need to set the same port between client and server. But I don't know what this means or how to do it. I've tryed many variations, but the basic structure I've been using is the one provided in the documentation:

```
connection = pymonetdb.connect(database = 'Main_Database', username="monetdb", password="monetdb", hostname="localhost")
```

I'd like to get to the point where my CSV dataframe is fully loaded and I can start doing operations with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it)