# Need help in sending email notification in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hey guys i want to send an email in rails when i click  the place order button to a user email id but i get this error when i click the button `undefined method 'items' for #<Order:0x6d83c48>` 
this my order_mailer.rb in mailer folder

```
class OrderMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: "gokuverma94@gmail.com"


    def order_confirmation order
        @order=order
        mail to: order.user.email, subject: "Your order (##{order.id})"
    end
end
```

and this is my orders_controller.rb

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @order_form=OrderForm.new(user: User.new(order_params[:user]),cart: @cart)
        if @order_form.save
            notify_user
            redirect_to root_path,notice:"Thank You for placing the order sir."
        else
        render "carts/checkout"
        end
    end

   private

    def notify_user
      OrderMailer.order_confirmation(@order_form.order).deliver  
    end

    def order_params
        params.require(:order_form).permit(
            user:[:name,:phone,:address,:city,:country,:postal_code,:email])
    end
end
```

and finally my order_confirmation.text.erb in the views/order_mailer folder

```
<h2>Hello</h2><%=@order.user.name%>,
Thank you for placing an order. Here is a summary for order #<%=@order.id%>:
<% @order.items.each do |item|%>
*<%=item.quantity%><%=item.product.name%>($<%=item.total_price%>)
<%end%>
Total: $<%=@order.total_price%>
```

@order.user.name is working fine but,
I dont know why it cannot find the items method in order can someone please tell me what is wrong with it because i just cant seem to figure it out

cart.rb

```
class Cart
attr_reader :items

    def self.build_from_hash (hash)
        items= if hash["cart"] then 
            hash["cart"]["items"].map do |item_data|
            CartItem.new item_data["product_id"],item_data["quantity"]
            end
            else
            []
        end
        new items 
     end

    def initialize items=[]
        @items=items
    end

    def add_item (product_id)
        item=@items.find { |item| item.product_id == product_id}
        if item
            item.increment
        else
        @items << CartItem.new(product_id)
    end
    end

    def empty?
        @items.empty?
    end

    def count
        @items.length
    end

    def grand_total
        @items.inject(0){|sum,item| sum+item.total_price}
    end

    def serialize
        items = @items.map do |item|
            {
                "product_id" =>item.product_id,
                "quantity" => item.quantity
         }
        end
        {
                "items" => items
         }
    end
end
```

order_item.rb

```
class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product

    def total_price
        self.product.price*self.quantity
    end
end
```

cart_item.rb

```
 class CartItem
    attr_reader :product_id,:quantity
    def initialize (product_id,quantity=1)
        @product_id=product_id
        @quantity=quantity
    end
    def increment
        @quantity=@quantity+1
    end
    def product
        Product.find product_id
    end 
     def total_price
         product.price*quantity
     end
end
```

Comment: can you share order.rb file. Have you defined the associations properly?

Comment: these are the models

Comment: class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
   has_many :order_items
    
    def total_price
        order_items.inject(0){|sum, item| sum +item.total_price }
    end
end

Comment: this is the cart which containes items

Answer (score 0):

From your model data order does not have items, so you cant use `@order.items`
Replace `<% @order.items.each do |item|%>` with `<% @order.order_items.each do |item|%>`

Comment: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) for nil port 25

Comment: So I guess I answered your question. This new issue can be caused due to various reasons. This may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it