# unable to connect bluestacks with android studio to localhost:5555 in windows

Tags: android, android-studio, localhost, ports, bluestacks

```
unable to connect to localhost:5555: cannot connect to localhost:5555: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
```

**Got this error while trying to connect bluestacks to android studio in windows 10.**

> using a laptop with intel pentium p6100. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it)

Comment: I am trying to conect to localhost here !!!

Answer (score 2):

don't know if too late, but try:

```
adb connect 127.0.0.1:5555
```

For Windows PowerShell:

```
./adb connect 127.0.0.1:5555
```

If it's for use with Android Studio, first open Bluestacks and then Android Studio.

Cheers.