# How to fix No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:64527

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.6.1

I have an MVC application which depends on a web API application, I hosted the two on a shared hosting environment. API on the subdomain and MVC on the main domain the API is api.mydomain.com and the MVC is mydomain.com, the API works fine anytime I try it on postman or browser but the MVC cannot connect to it with the following error.

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it 127.0.0.1:64527    Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
>   review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection
>   could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it 127.0.0.1:64527
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace
>   below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SocketException (0x274d): No connection could be made because the
>   target machine actively refused it127.0.0.1:64527]
>    System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +6995036
>    System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +84
>    System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception) +256
>
> [WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
>    System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +606    System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +64
>
> [HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.]
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +28    SMMClient.<Setting>d__119`1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Dload\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\SMM\SMMClient\Proc.cs:1369
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +28    SIMSClient.Controllers.<Index>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Dload\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\SMM\SMMClient\Controllers\HomeController.cs:19
>
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>
>    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58
>
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +97
>
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +17
>
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34
>
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
>   +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
>   +228    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34
>
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
>   +26    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100
>
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +48
>
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>
>    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +48
>
>    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +38    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +22
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +48
>
>    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>
>    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +48
>    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +28    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar)
>   +152    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +125

This is how I connect to the API from Global.asax.cs

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        Proc.Configure("https://api.mydomain.com/");
    }
}
```

This is how I call a resource

```
public static class Proc
{
    private static HttpClient _client;
    public static void Configure(string Baseurl)
    {
        _client = new HttpClient();
        _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);

        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        //Define request data format  
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    }

    public static async Task<T> Settings<T>()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Account.AccessToken))
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Account.AccessToken);

        var resp = await _client.GetAsync($"api/superadmin/settings");

        var txt = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(txt);
    }
}
```

I'm able to connect to the live API from my local MVC application but I can not connect to the API from live MVC application.

I will be glad to get some help.

Comment: `https://api.mydomain.com/api/superadmin/settings` is that working URL? How do you run it? Host in IIS or in debug from VS?

Comment: Its a working URL and It was hosted on a shared hosting server

Answer (score 6):

This error occur when your firewall blocking the connection or process that is hosting the service is not listening on that port.
Refer these links:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1223846.aspx/1

[No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it)

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/426966/System-Net-Sockets-SocketExcep

Comment: Thanks Muhammad its now working all I did was redeploy my mvc project I changed it from Debug to Release

Answer (score 4):

This error is a network-related error occurred while establishing a connection to the Server. It means that the error is occurring because there is no server listening at the hostname and port you assigned. It literally means that the machine exists but that it has no services listening on the specified port .

Comment: I was using an example with a two part solution  (https://thesharperdev.com/examples-using-httpclient-in-fsharp/) . One part to create and run the sample server on localhost, and the second to run the client. When I got this error I assumed it was due to a firewall, but it was, as per this answer "there is no server listening at the hostname and port you assigned". The server had stopped, so I just restarted it and then the client worked. I re-enabled the Windows Firewall, and it still ran OK.

Answer (score 2):

My case is losing https so need to add binding again
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when using Visual Studio 2022 and trying to debug an MVC app. Fixing it was as simple as enabling multiple startup projects in the solution (both the MVC project and the API project). By default, only the MVC app was starting.

Answer (score 0):

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:64527

I went to the `Web.config` and changed the `127.0.0.1:64527` to the server which hosts my ASP.NET Web site. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

For me, this error was occurring when I had the wrong version of Node installed for the application I was trying to run. I'd upgraded to v18 a few weeks back and going back to v16 fixed this issue in my case!