# Chat server and chat client

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, network-programming

This program has both the ChatServer class and ChatClient class in the same file, and should be called in the terminal by `--name=server --port=8800` for the server and `--name=client1 --port=8800` for the client. The problem comes from the client class not being able to complete a try:

When running the program with server name, it seems to work fine. When it runs with client name, I get the output `Failed to connect to chat server @ port 8800`.

You can find where this except statement lies.

```
import select
import socket
import sys
import signal
import _pickle as cPickle
import struct
import argparse

SERVER_HOST = 'localhost'
CHAT_SERVER_NAME = 'server'

# Some utilities
def send(channel, *args):
    buffer = cPickle.dumps(args)
    value = socket.htonl(len(buffer))
    size = struct.pack("L", value)

    channel.send(size)
    channel.send(buffer)

def receive(channel):
    size = struct.calcsize("L")
    size = channel.recv(size)
    try:
        size = socket.ntohl(struct.unpack("L", size)[0])
    except struct.error as e:
        return ''
    buf = ""
    while len(buf) < size:
        buf = channel.recv(size - len(buf))
    return cPickle.loads(buf)[0]

class ChatServer(object):

    def __init__(self, port, backlog=5):
        self.clients = 0
        self.clientmap = {}
        self.outputs = []
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        # Enable re-using socket address
        self.server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.server.bind((SERVER_HOST, port))
        print('Server listening to port: %s...' % port)
        self.server.listen(backlog)
        # Catch keyboard interrupts
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.sighandler)

    def sighandler(self, signum, frame):
        # Close the server
        print("Shutting down server...")
        # Close existing client sockets
        for output in self.outputs:
            output.close()
        self.server.close()

    def get_client_name(self,client):
        info = self.clientmap[client]
        host, name = info[0][0], info[1]
        return '@'.join((name, host))

    def run(self):
        inputs = [self.server, sys.stdin]
        self.outputs = []
        running = True
        while running:
            try:
                readable, writeable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, self.outputs, [])
            except select.error as e:
                break
            for sock in readable:
                if sock == self.server:
                    # handle the server socket
                    client, address = self.server.accept()
                    print("Chat Server: got connection %d from %s" % (client.fileno(), address))
                    # Read the login name
                    cname = receive(client).split('NAME: ')[1]
                    # Compute client name ad send back
                    self.clients += 1
                    send(client, 'CLIENT: ' + str(address[0]))
                    inputs.append(client)
                    self.clientmap[client] = (address, cname)
                    # Send joining information to other clients
                    msg = "\n(Connected: New client (%d) from %s)" % (self.clients, self.get_client_name(client))
                    for output in self.outputs:
                        send(output, msg)
                    self.outputs.append(client)
                elif sock == sys.stdin:
                # Handle standard input
                junk = sys.stdin.readline()
                running = False
                else:
                    # Handle all other sockets
                    try:
                        data = receive(sock)
                        if data:
                            # Send as new client's message..
                        msg = '\n[' + self.get_client_name(sock) + ']>>' + data
                        # Send data to all except ourself
                        for output in self.outputs:
                            if output != sock:
                                send(output, msg)
                        else:
                            print("Chat server: %d hung up" % sock.fileno())
                            self.clients -= 1
                            sock.close()
                            inputs.remove(sock)
                            self.outputs.remove(sock)
                            # Sending client leaving info to others
                            msg = "\n(Now hung up: Client from %s" % self.get_client_name(sock)
                            for output in self.outputs:
                                send(output, msg)
                    except socket.error as e:
                        # Remove
                        inputs.remove(sock)
                        self.outputs.remove(sock)
            self.server.close()

class ChatClient(object):

    def __init__(self, name, port, host=SERVER_HOST):
        self.name = name
        self.connected = False
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        # Initial Prompt
        self.prompt = '[' + '@'.join((name, socket.gethostname().split('.')[0])) + ']> '
        # Connect to server at port
        try:
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.sock.connect((host, self.port))
            print("Now connected to chat server@ port %d" % self.port)
            self.connected = True
            # Send by name...
            send(self.sock, 'NAME: ' + self.name)
            data = receive(self.sock)
            # Contains client address, set it
            addr = data.split('CLIENT: ')[1]
            self.prompt = '[' + '@'.join((self.name, addr)) + ']>'
        except socket.error as e:
            print("Failed to connect to chat server @ port %d" % self.port)
            sys.exit(1)

    def run(self):
        while self.connected:
            try:
                sys.stdout.write(self.prompt)
                sys.stdout.flush()
                # Wait for input from stdin and socket
                readable, writable, exceptional = select.select([0, self.sock], [], [])
                for sock in readable:
                    if sock == 0:
                        data = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
                        if data:
                            send(self.sock, data)
                    elif sock == self.sock:
                        data = receive(self.sock)
                        if not data:
                            print('Client shutting down')
                            self.connected = False
                            break
                        else:
                            sys.stdout.write(data + '\n')
                            sys.stdout.flush()

            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print("Client interrupted")
                self.sock.close()
                break



if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Socket Server Example with Select')
    parser.add_argument('--name', action="store", dest="name", required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--port', action="store", dest="port", type=int, required=True)
    given_args = parser.parse_args()
    port = given_args.port
    name = given_args.name
    if name == CHAT_SERVER_NAME:
        server = ChatServer(port)
        server.run()
    else:
        client = ChatClient(name=name, port=port)
        client.run()
```

Comment: Before you run the client you need to have a server running that is listening on port 8800. Did you do that?

Comment: if you was printed that error what you stored as **e** you was be able to see you got an `[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it` and funny enough, I found [this helpfully on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63915036/10234009). I test it my self, and seams to work but because I do not know socket library already I got another error on your code. Over all seams to work the server and client connections, just data send it between them will brake the connection.