# I cannot connect MySQL web server

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

I added a database to my cPanel, but I cannot connect it.

```
try{
$db = new 
PDO('mysql:host=markus.veridyen.com;dbname=sosyalki_pratiki1_ipss;charset=utf8','sosyalki','password');
}catch(PDOException $e){
echo 'Hata: '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

When I try to connect my database, it gives me this error message:

Hata: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] The connection could not be established because the target machine actively refused.

Notice: Undefined variable: db in C:\xampp\htdocs\ipss\survey.php on line 55

Comment: Is that a remote machine, of so it would be uncommon to allow anyone to connect to it remotely.

Comment: Yes it's remote machine. if it's not  allowing,  is there anything possible that I can understand it doesn't allow?

Comment: When I make host=localhost it gives me this error: Hata: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'sosyalki_funnel'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55600630/how-to-fix-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refus OR  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695224/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it-127-0   OR not enough (useful) info to give a proper answer.

Comment: The mysql server likely has a firewall rule closing off port 3306. "actively refused" means that the connection attempt went through, but the remote server said "no, go away". That said, opening 3306 to the internet would be a fantastically bad idea. Only open it for the IP  you're connecting from, or set up tunneling.

Comment: allow `3306 TCP` in firewall and use `localhost`

Comment: Change the **host=markus.veridyen.com** to **"host=localhost"** inside the sever and try the code inside the server

Comment: @Indian how can I allow that in cpanel?

Comment: @OzanBilgiç In you cpanel, you can see an option `Remote Mysql` , Just add your ip address

Comment: @OzanBilgiç to know your public IP just search on google `my ip`

Comment: @OzanBilgiç or Just put `%` Wildcard if you want to allow any public ip address

Comment: @OzanBilgiç and also use your server domain for connecting to Remotehost from your local computer

Comment: I did all of these, but I still get this error message:  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'sosyalki'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sosyalki_deneme;charset=utf8','sosyalki','cpanelpassword');
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Connected successfully";
      } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
      }

sosyalki is my cpanel name

Answer (score 0):

You still can use localhost as server name on a live server.

I'll assume you are using cpanel.

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username"; //your cpanel username
$password = "password"; //your cpanel password

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=DatabaseName", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  echo "Connected successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: unfortunately this is not working too. It gives me this error message:  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'sosyalki'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: basically you put a wrong password thats all.

Comment: if you are using cpanel use your cpanel username and password. The one you are using to log in.