# Problem connection with a websocket server and client

Tags: c#, websocket

I have a connection problem between a python-encoded server that works with websockets and a client that works with websockets too.

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; using System.Text; 
using System.Threading.Tasks; 
using WebSocketSharp;

namespace test1 {

class Program  {

static void Main(string[] args)  
{    
    using (var ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.43.37:8080"))
    {
        ws.Connect();
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
 }
```

When the program is generated it shows me that

```
25/04/2019 09:48:31|Fatal|WebSocket.Connect|System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Aucune connexion n'a pu être établie car l'ordinateur cible l'a expressément refusée 192.168.43.37:8080
                             à System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor(String hostname, Int32 port)
                             à WebSocketSharp.WebSocket.setClientStream()
                             à WebSocketSharp.WebSocket.doHandshake()
                             à WebSocketSharp.WebSocket.connect()
```

Comment: Please never post code as screen shot - instead copy/paste the code as text

Comment: Both of your screen shots could be posted as **TEXT** - Please post the text instead of images

Comment: yes sorry , i'm new on this forum

Comment: i think it comes from firewall but i don't know but when I disable firewalls it still doesn't work, could you help me pls ?

Answer (score 0):

My French is rusty, but I'm pretty sure that exception translates to the target machine actively refused the connection.

I don't think there's anything wrong with your code.

Check that port 8080 is open on the remote machine
Check that the web service  / API end point is available in a browser.

This post contains a number of other possibilities to check: [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it)

Comment: Yes, No connection could be established because the target computer explicitly denied it 192.168.43.37:8080 and when im looking on my server(raspberry pi) i listen the 8080 port :

Comment: And can you please tell me how i can check if the port 8080 is open on the remote machine ?? and how i can  check the web service/API end point is available in a browser?? (I work on visual studio for the client and raspberry pi for the server )

Answer (score 0):

`var http = require('http').createServer(handler);`

`var fs = require('fs');`

`var io = require('socket.io')(http);`

`console.log('Server lauching');`
`http.listen(8080);`            //Listen on port 8080

`function handler (req, res) { //create server`

`fs.readFile(__dirname+'/index.html', function(err, data) {` //read corresponding file in folder

`if (err) {`

`res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});` //display 404 on error

`return res.end("404 Not Found");`

`}`

`res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});` //write HTML

`res.write(data);`

`return res.end();`

`});`
`}`

`io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {`

```
`socket.on('config', function (data){`  //When the webserver receives a websocket in channel 'config', logs the data and send a response to confirm for the user
    `console.log("data received");`
    `console.log(data);`
    `socket.emit('config', {'received':true});`
`});`
```

`});`