# Connecting to local IP address | C# Sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, lan

I followed a short tutorial on socket programming and ended up being able to send data to myself on the same computer. Now I want to be able to send data to another computer in my house.

This is how I have set up the endpoints.

Server:

```
    IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    IPAddress ipAdress = host.AddressList[0];
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAdress, 11000);
```

Client:

```
    IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    IPAddress ipAdress = host.AddressList[0];
    IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAdress, 11000);
```

I thought all I would have to do is set the IP on the client to the IP of the receiving computer like this:

```
    IPAddress ipAdress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.200.97");
    IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAdress, 11000);
```

but that doesn't seem to work. When I try it it says that the server is actively refusing connection.

Comment: Mark sure the software **firewall** on your server is turned off.  WindowsKey --> Type Firewall --> Turn it off Temporarily.

Comment: This might help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it

Comment: None of this seems to work :/  I am using the same exact project on both computers not sure if that makes a difference at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. The first entry in

```
IPAddress ipAdress = host.AddressList[0];
```

didn't give me my own IP address on the server.