# No connection could be made because the target machine active refused it?

Tags: c#, .net

My problem is weird and i was not able to find a resolution from referring to other threads regarding this. I am getting the error when i run the microsoft Synchronous Server Socket Example, Synchronous Client Socket Example, on two systems which are part of the domain but i do not get this error when i run the same code on two systems which are part of the network but they are not part of the domain! Anyone know what might be causing the issue?

The things i have done to try to resolve are I made sure the port was open, switched off the firewall and antivirus as suggested by others with similar problem.But it has not helped.

Server code:

```
using System;  
using System.Net;  
using System.Net.Sockets;  
using System.Text;  

public class SynchronousSocketListener {  

// Incoming data from the client.  
public static string data = null;  

public static void StartListening() {  
    // Data buffer for incoming data.  
    byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];  

    // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.  
    // Dns.GetHostName returns the name of the   
    // host running the application.  
    IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());  
    IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];  
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);  

    // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
    Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,  
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );  

    // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and   
    // listen for incoming connections.  
    try {  
        listener.Bind(localEndPoint);  
        listener.Listen(10);  

        // Start listening for connections.  
        while (true) {  
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");  
            // Program is suspended while waiting for an incoming connection.  
            Socket handler = listener.Accept();  
            data = null;  

            // An incoming connection needs to be processed.  
            while (true) {  
                int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);  
                data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes,0,bytesRec);  
                if (data.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1) {  
                    break;  
                }  
            }  

            // Show the data on the console.  
            Console.WriteLine( "Text received : {0}", data);  

            // Echo the data back to the client.  
            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);  

            handler.Send(msg);  
            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);  
            handler.Close();  
        }  

    } catch (Exception e) {  
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
    }  

    Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");  
    Console.Read();  

}  

public static int Main(String[] args) {  
    StartListening();  
    return 0;  
 }  
}
```

Client Code::

```
using System;  
using System.Net;  
using System.Net.Sockets;  
using System.Text;  

public class SynchronousSocketClient {  

public static void StartClient() {  
    // Data buffer for incoming data.  
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];  

    // Connect to a remote device.  
    try {  
        // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.  
        // This example uses port 11000 on the local computer.    
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("172.21.98.122");//Server IP  
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress,11000);  

        // Create a TCP/IP  socket.  
        Socket sender = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,   
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );  

        // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.  
        try {  
            sender.Connect(remoteEP);  

            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",  
                sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());  

            // Encode the data string into a byte array.  
            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is a test<EOF>");  

            // Send the data through the socket.  
            int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);  

            // Receive the response from the remote device.  
            int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);  
            Console.WriteLine("Echoed test = {0}",  
                Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes,0,bytesRec));  

            // Release the socket.  
            sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);  
            sender.Close();  

        } catch (ArgumentNullException ane) {  
            Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}",ane.ToString());  
        } catch (SocketException se) {  
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}",se.ToString());  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());  
        }  

    } catch (Exception e) {  
        Console.WriteLine( e.ToString());  
    }  
}  

public static int Main(String[] args) {  
    StartClient();  
    return 0;  
 }  
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you're using, not just a link. Note that there are many reasons this can occur: see [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2972600/215552)

Comment: Just posted the code, Thanks.