# How to solve python selenium os error 10061?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I was testing a program that I found to open instagram in firefox using selenium.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/')

sleep(5)

browser.close()
```

In theory the program should work but I get the error: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: A connection cannot be established as the target computer expressly denied said connection. (os error 10061). Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Is the website accessible from your browser? The above code works fine for me.

Comment: Yes, manually if it let me

Comment: may be a proxy or a firewall which might be blocking

Comment: Most likely you have closed the browser window, and tried to run part of te script after that.Also try to specify path and make sure you see a shell open and browser after that (does the browser open?).
from selenium import webdriver
geckodriver = r'geckodriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=geckodriver)
print('Selenium webdriver setup complete')
for x in range(2):
    driver.get('https://www.google.com')
    driver.save_screenshot('data/WorkArea/image{}.png'.format(x))
    print('Took screenshot {}'.format(x))
driver.quit()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it