# A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server

Tags: c#, visual-studio

A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session. The status of the exception was UnknownError, and the message was: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

how to resolve above issue ?

Comment: Was it a `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException` exception ?

Comment: This is might be of many reasons but mostly a Firewall issue, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it) it might help you.  If not,  update the question with some more details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.