# How do I get around this error in my .net application

Tags: c#, .net, socketexception

This is my error

> SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

I am getting it on this code

```
public class AppService : IAppService
{
    public async Task<MainResponse> AuthenticateUser(LoginModel loginModel)
    {
        var returnResponse = new MainResponse();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var url = $"{Setting.BaseUrl}{UserAPIs.AuthenticateUser}";

            var serializedStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginModel);

            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(serializedStr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string contentStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                returnResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainResponse>(contentStr);
            }
        }

        return returnResponse;
    }
}
```

This is my controller code for the API
All of my port numbers are right
and all other API's are running correctly
I just cant get passed the log in with the username and password

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("AuthenticateUser")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AuthenticateUser(LoginModel authenticateUser)
    {
        try
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(authenticateUser.UserName);
            if (user == null) return Unauthorized();

            bool isValidUser = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, authenticateUser.Password);

            if (isValidUser)
            {
                string accessToken = GenerateAccessToken(user);
                var refreshToken = GenerateRefreshToken();
                await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

                var role = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

                int? roleID = null;
                switch (role?.FirstOrDefault())
                {
                    case "Admin":
                        roleID = (int)RoleEnum.Admin;
                        break;
                    case "Student":
                        roleID = (int)RoleEnum.Student;
                        break;
                    case "Teacher":
                        roleID = (int)RoleEnum.Teacher;
                        break;
                }

                var response = new MainResponse
                {
                    Content = new AuthenticationResponse
                    {
                        RefreshToken = refreshToken,
                        AccessToken = accessToken,
                        RoleID = roleID
                    },
                    IsSuccess = true,
                    ErrorMessage = ""
                };
                return Ok(response);
            }

            else
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var response = new MainResponse
            {
                Content = new AuthenticationResponse
                {
                    RefreshToken = null,
                    AccessToken = null,
                    RoleID = null,
                    DeviceToken = null
                },
                IsSuccess = true,
                ErrorMessage = ex.Message
            };
            return Ok(response);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it)

Comment: This typically occurs when the API is not running (or where you expect it to run). Are you sure the API your calling is up and running at the specified URL. Check domain and port.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it)

Answer (score 0):

Try these..

1. Make sure the API is Up.
2. Check the URL
3. Add exception handling in your code

   public async Task AuthenticateUser(LoginModel loginModel)
   {
   var returnResponse = new MainResponse();

   ```
   try
   {
       using (var client = new HttpClient())
       {
           var url = $"{Setting.BaseUrl}{UserAPIs.AuthenticateUser}";

           var serializedStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginModel);

           var response = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(serializedStr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

           if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           {
               string contentStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
               returnResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainResponse>(contentStr);
           }
       }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       // Log or display the exception details for troubleshooting.
       Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
       // You can also throw the exception if needed.
       // throw;
   }

   return returnResponse;
   ```

   }