# What cause my C# socket connection to port 2131 to be refused?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, service, protocols

There is a server running on 192.168.0.10 we lost power and the server had to restart, the thing is our application have a function called StartReceive() that create a Socket then call a socket.Connect(IPEndPoint). But I get this error "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it "192.168.0.10:2131""
I am new at this company and I am the only one, every one is on leave for the next 2 weeks. I've gathered some information but nothing seems to fit together, I feel like I am missing a piece of the puzzle.

I've read these, but nothing helped me:

1. http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/connection.htm
2. [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972600/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it)
3. https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5332894/System-net-sockets-socketexception-no-connection-c
4. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/626063/no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-mac

At the top of my class I have this:

```
public static string DBAvantage = "02"; 
 public static string PassAvantage = "PASSWORD";

List<string> lcommande = new List<string> { "LOGIN," + DBEngine.DBAvantage + ",OPERATEUR," + DBEngine.PassAvantage + "\n" };
```

These infos let me think that Advantage is a DB

When I the code run and it get to the function StartReceive(), it crash and I get this error
"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it "192.168.0.10:2131""

```
private void StartRecieve()
        {
            s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            IPAddress hostadd = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.10");
            int port = Int32.Parse("2131");
            IPEndPoint EPhost = new IPEndPoint(hostadd, port);

            s.Connect(EPhost);

            int cnt = 0;
            string tmp = null;
            Byte[] firstb = new Byte[1];
            bool finish = false;
            while (!finish)
            {
                try
                {
                    Byte[] receive = new Byte[1];
                    int ret = s.Receive(receive);
                    if (ret > 0)
                    {
                        switch (receive[0])
                        {
                            case 11: //check start message
                                cnt = 0;
                                break;
                            case 10: // check end message
                                cnt = 0;
                                finish = HandleText(tmp);
                                tmp = null;
                                if (ncommande < lcommande.Count)
                                {
                                    Byte[] bBuf;
                                    string buf;

                                    buf = String.Format(lcommande[ncommande]);
                                    bBuf = ASCII.GetBytes(buf);
                                    s.Send(bBuf, 0, bBuf.Length, 0);
                                    ncommande++;
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                if (cnt == 0)
                                    firstb[0] = receive[0];
                                tmp += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receive);
                                cnt++;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    if (!s.Connected)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            s.Disconnect(true);
            t.Abort();
        }
```

I tried to look on internet what is running on port 2131. I found this:
[Port 2131 internet search result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuJNd.png)

I've been trying to search things about the service avantageb2b, but nothing comes out on internet. This is the only informations I've found. Is it possible to restart this service ? What can I do ? My guest is the power loss made the server restart but this service didn't restart has it should have been and when I try to listen at it, it can't.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using raw sockets instead of TcpClient? But it sounds like there just isn't anything listening on port 2131...

Comment: This is not my code, this is one of my coworker who did this part. It was working fine for the last months/years and now it stopped working and Idk why. So the shouldn't be the problem. As I said my guest is the server is the problem

Comment: Well yes, it sounds like the server isn't running - contrary to your very first sentence. (Or the server's firewall is blocking you...)

Comment: PLEASE  tell me that `t` is not a `Thread` ...

Comment: I already tried to add TCP/UDP inbound and outbound rule on port 2131 in the server and it didn't change anything. The server is running, I am currently connected to it via RDP.

Comment: Well it seems the T is Thread, can you explain to me what does it do ?

Comment: `t.Abort` is deprecated, doesn't work at all on .NET Core, and is overall a bad idea. Use `CancellationToken` and async functions. This code needs a complete rewrite to be honest.

Comment: A UDP rule won't cut it because the protocol is TCP. Also,  not only the Serv**er** needs to run but also the Serv**ice** that listens on that port.

Comment: And I second Charlieface: that code needs to be hauled into 2023. But better not open too many construction sites at once. First get it to connect again.

Comment: The thing is I don't know what service runs on that port. As I said I found really little informations about what runs on this port. I would guess it is avantageb2b, but I searched how to restart this service and found nothing about it, which is the point to my question, does anyone know anything about this service

Answer (score 0):

it's your accounting software "avantage" that simply didn't restart. Here is the website of the software you are looking for. Open the server, type avantage and restart it.

https://www.avantage.ca/